# Get amount of memory used by app in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I'm working on an upload app that splits files before upload. It splits the files to prevent being closed by iOS for using too much memory as some of the files can be rather large. It would be great if I could, instead of setting the max "chunk" size, set the max memory usage and determine the size using that.

Something like this

```
#define MAX_MEM_USAGE 20000000 //20MB
#define MIN_CHUNK_SIZE 5000   //5KB

-(void)uploadAsset:(ALAsset*)asset
{
    long totalBytesRead = 0;
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    while(totalBytesRead < [representation size])
    {
        long chunkSize = MAX_MEM_USAGE - [self getCurrentMemUsage];
        chunkSize = min([representation size] - totalBytesRead,max(chunkSize,MIN_CHUNK_SIZE));//if I can't get 5KB without getting killed then I'm going to get killed
        uint8_t *buffer = malloc(chunkSize);
        //read file chunk in here, adding the result to totalBytesRead
        //upload chunk here
    }
}
```

Is essentially what I'm going for. I can't seem to find a way to get the current memory usage of my app specifically. I don't really care about the amount of system memory left.

The only way I've been able to think of is one I don't like much. Grab the amount of system memory on the first line of main in my app, then store it in a static variable in a globals class then the getCurrentMemUsage would go something like this

```
-(long)getCurrentMemUsage
{
    long sysUsage = [self getSystemMemoryUsed];
    return sysUsage - [Globals origSysUsage];
}
```

This has some serious drawbacks. The most obvious one to me is that another app might get killed in the middle of my upload, which could drop sysUsage lower than origSysUsage resulting in a negative number even if my app is using 10MB of memory which could result in my app using 40MB for a request rather than the maximum which is 20MB. I could always set it up so it clamps the value between MIN_CHUNK_SIZE and MAX_MEM_USAGE, but that would just be a workaround instead of an actual solution.

If there are any suggestions as to getting the amount of memory used by an app or even different methods for managing a dynamic chunk size I would appreciate either.

Comment: I would just use 256KB chunks and be done with it. Is there some significant advantage to having chunks larger than that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Just that it speeds up the upload process significantly. The user could be uploading files over 1gb in size, so it would take an insanely large number of chunks to upload it. It would take a lot of chunks at 20MB, but still better than 256KB (or some other smaller value). Also, some files don't need the full 20MB of memory to upload (a jpeg for instance). Our goal for this app is to be able to upload as quickly as possible in as few requests as possible without running out of memory.

Comment: at least it sped up the upload process on android, I'm sure it would on iOS devices as well

Comment: I would try to figure out why your application needs such large buffers to reach peak performance and fix that, rather than trying to work around the defect.

Comment: The server I'm uploading to needs the file parts in order, so I have to wait for the server to give me a response that says it's ready for the next part before I can upload it. I haven't actually tested with anything larger than a 2MB buffer and a 20MB file, but the fewer requests I have the faster the upload completes. Before I put in file splitting, the 20MB file would upload very quickly (nearly instantly since it's over a LAN) which is why I'm picking 20MB as an ideal memory usage level.

Comment: There is no reason the server has to know or care what buffer size the client is using. It sounds like there's some very poor design in there somewhere. (Which might have been forced by unusual circumstances, I don't know.) The usual pattern is: Check size of file, tell server size of file, read chunk, write chunk, repeat, tell server we're done.

Comment: The server doesn't care about buffer size. It does have to do processing on the request before it can send the response. When it receives the data, it appends the data onto the end of the file it belongs to and, if all goes well, returns a 204 response at which point the client sends the next chunk. The buffer size doesn't change how long it takes to process a request (at least not noticeably), it just changes how many requests the client has to send to the server before the upload is complete which affects how fast the upload is able to complete

Comment: Then the design flaw is forcing the request size to equal the buffer size. That should be revisited and, unless absolutely mandatory, changed.

Answer (score 0):

Now, as with any virtual memory operating system, getting the "memory used" is not very well defined and is notoriously difficult to define and calculate.

Fortunately, thanks to the virtual memory manager, your problem can be solved quite easily: the [mmap()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) C function. Basically, it allows your app to virtually load the file into memory, treating it as if it were in RAM, but it is actually swapped in from storage as it is accessed, and swapped out when iOS is low on memory.

This function is really easy to use in iOS with the Cocoa APIs for it:

```
- (void) uploadMyFile:(NSString*)fileName {
    NSData* fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:fileName];
    // Work with the data as with any NSData* object. The iOS kernel
    // will take care of loading the file as needed.
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding the NSData to a POST request demand the entire file and load it all into memory anyway? I think I'm essentially doing the same thing already, using the getBytes method of the ALAssetRepresentation. I skip ahead to totalBytesRead and read in chunkSize bytes and then stick it on the POST request. From what I can tell, adding fileData to the request would demand all the pages at once and I would still be sitting with the entire file loaded into memory. I hope I'm wrong, because your solution looks really easy :)

Comment: No, it wouldn't - that is the beauty of memory-mapped files. For the technical details I recommend the Wikipedia article that I linked to. However, I can't say if it solves your specific problem or not, but I advice you to try it.